# IBM Watson Assistant: How can I filter messages for "anything else"?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In Analytics > User conversations, I would like to filter out the messages which my Watson Assistant was unable to answer in its conversations, i.e., when it returns the anything_else reply.

But since **anything_else** is not an intent nor an entity, I can't filter messages by it in the UI. Is it possible to therefore filter messages by the assistant's reply, like you can with user statements? That way I can filter out each time the assistant answered "I don't understand".

Answer (score 1):

IBM Watson Assistant offers the log in the Analytics section of it UI and, IMHO more powerful, via [REST API with filter expressions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-filter-reference#filter-reference). With that API you can either download all logs and filter "offline" or apply some expressions. I recommend reading the documentation about [how to query the "other" fields](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-filter-reference#filter-reference-fields) which includes the user responses.

I have written [Python tools for Watson Assistant](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) using the V1 and V2 APIs. The V1 tool is able to download or query the logs. An option is to download all available logs, then use **jq** to filter them.

```
python wctool.py -logs -config config.json.event -id 28ac4bcb-2aae-41aa-87ac-2e6074e1356a > logs201904.out
```

This gives you the information about which nodes were visited:

```
cat logs201904.out | jq -r '.logs | .[]
       | .response.output.nodes_visited   '
```

Filter for log records that visited "Anything else":

```
cat logs201904.out | jq -r '.logs | .[] | .response | select( 
    .output.nodes_visited[] | contains("Anything else")) '
```

Answer (score 1):

`anything_else` means either an intent was not found, or the confidence was  < 0.2.

Filter looking for intents = [], or confidence of first intent is below 20%